# Return lazy evaluation of list of boolean statements , with any of it true

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a series of boolean decision, each having a different condition to evaluate. If any of it evaluates to true it should return. Problem is, I do not want them to be eagerly evaluated. I have two implementations here, the first one works, but i have 10 such decisions to make so i want to get them all as a list,  as soon as I put them into list/stream it evaluates all the decisions and fails the purpose. What I want is, if any of the condition evaluates to true it should stop right there and return, rest of the conditions should not get executed.

```
BooleanSupplier a = () -> compute("bb");
BooleanSupplier b = () -> computeSecond("aa");

// this works
System.out.println("Lazy match => " + lazyMatch(a, b));

// this doesn't
System.out.println("Lazy match list => " + lazyMatchList(Stream.of(a,b)));

static boolean lazyMatch(BooleanSupplier a, BooleanSupplier b) {
        return a.getAsBoolean() || b.getAsBoolean();
}

static boolean lazyMatchList(Stream<BooleanSupplier> lazyBooleanList) {
        return  lazyBooleanList.anyMatch(BooleanSupplier::getAsBoolean);
}

static boolean compute(String str) {
        System.out.println("executing...");
        return str.contains("ac");
}

// compute2 is something similar to compute
```

Comment: *If any of it evaluates to true it should return* return True of False ?

Comment: "If any of it evaluates to true it should return." Did you mean "if any of it evaluates to ***false***"?

Comment: Your 2 method don't do the same, the `lazyMath` with `&&` will evaluate all whereas the other will stop at first true. Use `||` so sop at first true

Comment: edited the question and method as well.

Comment: So now, what the question , problem ? Because for both case, if `a` is true, it does not evaluate `b`

Comment: for me, both cases giving the same result, i.e true, so what the problem here?

Comment: yeah right, it's working. I was testing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Predicate<String>> predicates = Arrays.asList(this::compute1, this::compute2, ...);

boolean anyTrue(String str) {
    return predicates.stream()
      .anyMatch(p -> p.test(str));
}
```

This returns `true` when the first predicate returns true.

Use the method as a filter predicate:

```
someStringStream.filter(this::anyTrue)...
```

Comment: `anyMatch` is more apt for what you've suggested.